Exclude background in navbar of another page within the Nextjs App router
Now I know this is probably going to be an edge case in Nextjs, but I believe there's a loophole out there that could be done to solve this issue
While keeping the background color of the Navbar in the root section of the app layout the same.
Image
I would like to change the background color of the navbar in the about us page and make it transparent
I've tried everything, from using useRouter to pathname and rendering the bgColor conditionally, to creating two separate navbars and rendering them based on the pathname but I still couldn't figure out a solution
I really hope someone out here has a galaxy brain to fix this...

What is your Navbar code? I'm wondering it might be the router cache mechanism causing this issue, does it change bgColor after refresh page?
